# Deshabilitar php intl extension

Tags: .htaccess

Buenas tardes,

Acabo de migrar una web de un servidor a otro, y el nuevo usa una versión más moderna de PHP qué me crea un conflicto con la MUY antigua versión de framework en la que está hecha la web (es Silverstripe, poco conocido). El caso es que buscando y buscando parece que la solución pasa por desactivar la extensión intl, pero claro, tenemos varias webs en el servidor y sólo queremos desactivarlo en esa en particular, así que había pensado en hacerlo a través de htaccess. Pero he fracasado estrepitosamente en todos mis intentos... Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente me he rendido y lo he desactivado en todo el server. Todo funciona de momento, pero cómo no sé exactamente que hace esa extensión no sé si tendré que lamentarlo en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que visto así, me he explicado entre tirando a muy mal y fatal... Solo tengo una versión de PHP en este servidor. Migré hace poco todas las webs de uno al otro, pero esta en concreto, es una versión muy antigua de SilverStripe y al parecer hay una incompatibilidad entre una de sus librerias y el phpintl (silverstripe.org/community/forums/hosting-requirements/show‌​/…) Cuando instalé PHP venía incluído en con Kloxo así que supongo que es precompilado. SilverStripe es compatible, es solo una librería que crea conflictos. Gracias!